# Custom HTML ticks on y-axis ChartJS

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart, ng2-charts

I want to create custom ticks on Y-Axis.
I couldn't get it working. I have tried with multiple ticks configuration but nothing seems to support HTML template.

[image: Chart]

Comment: Chart.js does not support html ticks

Comment: @LeeLenalee any customization possible?

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration

Comment: I meant some custom code/plugin to achieve that

Comment: Well yeah you can write a custom plugin for it yourself, dont know of any plugin that does it currently as detailed as you want